# Проблема с отправкой почты из PHP скрипта

Tags: php, email

Есть страничка send.php на ней принятие массива пост,
и отправка письма на емейл, и сразу идет переадресация на 
header("location:тут главная страничка");
и все вроде бы хорошо!
Но перед тем, как перейти на главную страницу, он зачем то показывает содержимое отправляемого письма на странице send.php.
а на ней нет выводов никаких.
в чем проблема подскажите?

Вот код:

```
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1251');
$email_to = '4up@mail.ru';
$name = $_POST['fio']; 
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
if($_POST['count']){
$count = $_POST['count']; 
}
else{
$count = 'не заполнено';
}
if($_POST['rayon']){
$rayon = $_POST['rayon']; 
}
else{
$rayon = 'не заполнено';
}
if($_POST['date']){
$date = $_POST['date']; 
}
else{
$date = 'не заполнено';
}
if($_POST['price']){
$price = $_POST['price']; 
}
else{
$price = 'не заполнено';
}
$type_deal = $_POST['type_check'];
$type_real_estate = $_POST['type_check2'];
$message = $_POST['comm'];
$message = "Имя : " . $name . "\r\n email : " . $email . "\r\n Телефон : " . $phone . "\r\n тип сделки : " . $type_deal . "\r\n Тип недвижимости : " . $type_real_estate ."\r\n количество комнат : ".$count."\r\n В районе : ".$rayon."\r\n Сроки сдачи : ".$date."\r\n Ориентировачная стоимость : ".$price."\r\n текст сообщения : " . $message;
$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email\r\n";
mail('4up@mail.ru',$headers,$message);
header("Главная страница");
```

Comment: @adun, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: а зачем мне отформатировать код?)

Comment: Во первых тут битриксом и не пахнет, во вторых либо перенаправляет либо показывает!!! По другому быть не может. Скорее всего никуда вас не перенаправялет.

Answer (score 1):

возможно это из-за того что вначале страницы указан

```
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1251');
```

т.е. вы указываете, что output текущей страницы является текстом

Comment: не решил проблему, закрыли доступ.
спасибо за ответ,
попытался "наградить"Вроде получилось, надеюсь плохого я ничего не сделал :)